# SQL Matrix to array

Tags: sql, arrays, t-sql, matrix, pivot

I am working with T-SQL and I have a table that looks like Matrix (8x8).
My objective is to make that Matrix (table) into array using Pivot ... I have read forums and more stuff that i managed to find but i still can't make a code for it ...

```
 ID     Bucket     B1     B2     B3     B4 
 5        1        20     21     45     12
 6        2        12     18     19     48
 7        3        19     78     40     78  
 8        4        72     34     12     17
```

So all I need to do is to make "three dimensional array" from that table, and to save row, column and value ... to be something like this

```
Row    Column   Value 
 1       1       20
 1       2       21
 1       3       45
 1       2       12
 etc
 etc
 etc
 4       3       12
 4       4       17
```

Does anyone have any idea how I could write that code in T-SQL?

ps. Reason i'm doing this, is because i want to multiply my matrix with itself. So it's easier to multiply it if i have it in pivot table.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try unpivoting your data :

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (id INT, Bucket INT, B1 INT, B2 INT, B3 INT, B4 INT)
INSERT INTO @table VALUES
(5,1,20,21,45,12),
(6,2,12,18,19,48),
(7,3,19,78,40,78),
(8,4,72,34,12,17)

SELECT rn AS [ROW],
VALUE AS [ColumnNumber],
orders AS [VALUE] 
FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn,id, Bucket, B1 [1], B2 [2], B3 [3], B4 [4]
FROM @table
) AS t
UNPIVOT
(
    orders
    FOR VALUE IN([1], [2],[3],[4])
) AS pvt
```

Check this [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) Doc for more details of PIVOT and UNPIVOT.

Comment: Beat me to it, this is definitely the best way to do this (in my opinion)

Answer (score 0):

Why use PIVOT?  You can get the data out with a simple SELECT query, unless I am missing something here?

```
DECLARE @Matrix TABLE (
    Id INT,
    Bucket INT,
    B1 INT,
    B2 INT,
    B3 INT,
    B4 INT);
INSERT INTO @Matrix VALUES (5, 1, 20, 21, 45, 12);
INSERT INTO @Matrix VALUES (6, 2, 12, 18, 19, 48);
INSERT INTO @Matrix VALUES (7, 3, 19, 78, 40, 78);
INSERT INTO @Matrix VALUES (8, 4, 72, 34, 12, 17);
SELECT
    Bucket AS [Row],
    1 AS [Column],
    B1 AS Value
FROM
    @Matrix
UNION ALL
SELECT
    Bucket AS [Row],
    2 AS [Column],
    B2 AS Value
FROM
    @Matrix
UNION ALL
SELECT
    Bucket AS [Row],
    3 AS [Column],
    B3 AS Value
FROM
    @Matrix
UNION ALL
SELECT
    Bucket AS [Row],
    4 AS [Column],
    B4 AS Value
FROM
    @Matrix
ORDER BY
    1, 2;
```

Results:

```
Row Column  Value
1   1   20
1   2   21
1   3   45
1   4   12
2   1   12
2   2   18
2   3   19
2   4   48
3   1   19
3   2   78
3   3   40
3   4   78
4   1   72
4   2   34
4   3   12
4   4   17
```