# Best method to split columns into rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, matrix

What would be the best method to split columns into rows (like matrix?)
Example table:

```
Name Hours1 Hours2 Hours3
Jon  32     40     30
Ana  40     0      40
```

Result (don't show 0 values):

```
Name Hours
Jon  32
Jon  40
Jon  30
Ana  40
Ana  40
```

One way I can think of doing this is by using `Union`

```
SELECT
  Name,
  Hours1
FROM #HOURSTABLE
WHERE Hours1 <> 0

UNION ALL

SELECT
  Name,
  Hours2
FROM #HOURSTABLE
WHERE Hours2 <> 0

UNION ALL

SELECT
  Name,
  Hours3
FROM #HOURSTABLE
WHERE Hours3 <> 0
```

Any other suggestion?

Comment: You could try to unpivot your data? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255284/sql-matrix-to-array

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I prefer the CROSS APPLY for such items.  It offers a bit more flexibility.

**Example**

```
Select Name
      ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (Hours1)
                     ,(Hours2)
                     ,(Hours3)
             ) B(Hours)
 Where B.Hours<>0
```

**Returns**

```
Name    Hours
Jon     32
Jon     40
Jon     30
Ana     40
Ana     40
```

Comment: Wow, very easy solution. Wasn't familiar with CROSS APPLY. Thank you!

Comment: @Stephanie Cross Apply and Outer Apply can be invaluable.  Especially useful with Table-Value-Functions   Happy it helps

Comment: Nice solution! I've always relied on Pivot/UnPivot for these situations.

Comment: @StelioK Thanks.  I like this approach because it is easy to extend or manipulate the values with other factors,

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to use `unpivot`

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

```
 declare @t table (name varchar(50), hours1 int, hours2 int, hours3 int)

 insert @t 
 select 'Jon ', 32     ,40     ,30
 union
 select 'Ana  ',40     ,0      ,40

 select name, hours from @t
 unpivot (hours for h in (hours1, hours2, hours3)) u
 where hours<>0
```

The full results from unpivot mean that you don't lose the information about which column the `hours` value was in (ie: hours1, hours2, hours3)

Comment: Thank you, this is also a great solution!